# Apparent Bug in Calculation of Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Set

`k=x/Abs[x]`

Then:

- when $x$ is set to $0$, $k$ is indeterminate

  the limit of $k$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ from below is a well-defined $-1$

  and

  the limit of $k$ as $x\rightarrow 1$ from above is a well-defined $1$

But when I enter

`Limit[k,x->0]`

Mathematica (at least in version 10.4, which I am using) blithely responds with

`1`

In other words, it gives me the limit from above, although this is not actually the limit (and there is no limit).

Is this a bug or is it some standard choice that Mathematica makes?

**Edited to add:** As the comments make clear, this was never a bug; it was an intentional choice, which has changed in later versions.

Comment: Don't use the [tag:bugs] tag unless the behavior you observe has been confirmed by other users to be a bug.

Comment: On that note, you really should have looked at the "Details and Options" section of the `Limit[]` doc page: **["`Limit[expr, x -> x0]` uses the setting `Direction -> Automatic`, which determines the direction from assumptions that have been given, using `Direction -> -1` as the default. For limit points at infinity, the direction is determined from the direction of the infinity."](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v10.4/ref/Limit.html#271203821)**

Comment: @J.M.: You are right; the direction option solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem in 12.1

```
ClearAll[x];
k = x/Abs[x];
Limit[k, x -> 0]

(*Indeterminate*)
```

---

### [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: It is possible to check with latest release of Mathematica if something is fixed, without installing V 12.1 at all by going to

http://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/view/newNotebook?ext=nb

This will open a new notebook in the cloud, running 12.1

**Answer comment**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Okay.   I'm using 10.4, which of course I should have said upfront.  Thank you.

Comment: If you've got the time and inclination, I'd be very interested to know whether 12.1 gets the following more complicated case right:  k=((i)^(i-1))Gamma[1-i]/Sqrt[2 i PolyGamma[0,1-i]+(i^2)PolyGamma[1,1-i]] .  The limit as $i$ goes to 3 (or for that matter any other positive integer) behaves just as for x/Abs[x], but Mathematica 10.4 insists on picking one of the two one-sided limits and calling it the limit.  That's the case I'm really interested in.

Comment: @WillO fyi, I posted a link to V12.1 which you can use now in the cloud. I've added the new example you have. It gives indeterminate also.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is all I need to know.  I remain mildly curious whether this behavior was a bug in 10.4 or an intentional choice.

Comment: @WillO - what do you get when you evaluate `Options[Limit, Direction]` in your version?

Comment: @BobHanlon:  The direction option solves the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @WillO - I recommend that you edit your question since you presumably now know "Is this a bug or is it some standard choice that Mathematica makes?"

Comment: @BobHanlon:  My experience at other StackExchange sites suggests that when a question receives a good answer, the right thing to do is to accept the answer, not to edit the question.  Is the etiquette different here?

Comment: @WillO - I am not an expert on etiquette; however, the accepted answer while pointing out that v12.1 behaves as expected, does not address whether earlier versions have a bug or it is some standard choice that Mathematica made. Since you presumably now have some insight into that aspect, "annotating" the question would improve its usefulness to users of earlier versions. They may or may not read all of the comments.